# composition of a continuous function with another function which is not uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

Suppose there are two continuous functions f and g, where f is uniformly continuous, whereas g is not uniformly continuous.  Is it possible for their composition to be uniformly continuous?

I have thought of a few examples but they turn out to be continuous functions which aren't uniformly continuous.

Comment: take $f$  constant, and $g$ anything you like. Then, $f\circ g$ is constant, hence uniformly continuous.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's an easy fix indeed.